# Synonym request: [korn] -> [ksh]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

There are currently 14 questions tagged [korn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/korn) which should probably all be tagged [ksh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ksh) instead. While I can do that myself, I would like to have [korn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/korn) be a synonym of [ksh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ksh) going forward. I can't even suggest this synonym because I don't have enough score in the tag. How should I proceed?

(In case you are not familiar with the terminology, the Korn shell is a Unix shell which is backwards-compatible with the standard Bourne shell, `sh`. The POSIX `sh` specification by and large accepted `ksh88` as the new baseline, though it took many implementers quite a while to adhere to the specification after this.)

Comment: Maybe [tag:korn] should also be renamed to [tag:korn-shell] to be more in line with the actual name?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat That sounds more like there should be yet another synonym for `ksh`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now completed.

I've merged [korn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/korn) into [ksh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ksh) and allowed a synonym to be created. I've also created [korn-shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/korn-shell) as a synonym for [ksh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ksh).

```
updating post history, 17 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 14 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 11 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'korn': [korn] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 history records for type Announcement had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Announcement had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 2746
tag remapping of [ksh] and [korn] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
50 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym korn -> ksh was approved!
```